# Another Term for "Long-Thought"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, adjectives, synonyms

So I was doing a bit of writing and ended up using the phrase "long-thought" (as in, "a technique long-thought forgotten" or "people long-thought incapable of using magic"). I ended up using it quite a few times and was wondering if anyone can come up with another phrase with the same (or a very similar) meaning so that I won't constantly be using the same word. Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1):

Synonyms to the rescue. The term is *Believed to be*. The Coelacanth was *believed to be* extinct until one showed up off the coast of Madagascar.

Answer (score 0):

**Received knowledge** was that Trump was not a serious candidate.

I learned this phrase from listening to BBC news programs.  It means what was popularly believed.

You can also use that: **popularly believed**.  For example:

> At one time, it was popularly believed that Mars was criss-crossed with canals.

The **common** or **popular conception** was that etc.

You can also try

> people previously thought [to be] incapable of using magic

In other words, leave out "long."  (This "to be" is optional.)